# Unable to create a new dart file

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I can't create a new dart file in android studio.Please help

[main.dart is auto created by android studio] [screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W4NR.png)

[flutter doctor is fine] [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66loF.png)

Comment: You can create files by right clicking the lib folder and then selecting new>dart file. and add a name to it. It will be created as Nameyougave.dart

Comment: you did the correct way, keep typing, or do a restart of `androidStudio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your flutter project in android studio. Go to android studio settings by following this flow. File => Settings => Languages & Frameworks and select Dart check its Sdk path is it correct or not and is the dart support is enabled for your project or not.

If this is all good then by right click at lib and hover on New => Dart File give it some name (extension is not required just name it) and you are good to work in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should right click on lib folder and create dart file or create file with extention **.dart** eg. **abc.dart**